# Center aligning a shrunk frame in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I have a beamer related question. I am using [shrink=50] command to shrink a frame. I want the shrunk frame to be center aligned but by default it is aligned left of the slide. How do I do this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=50]
\textbf{Title of the slide}
\vskip10pt
Hi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume you've read Till Tantau's advice: "Never ever use the evil option `shrink`."

Comment: You can just wrap the contents in a `center` environment.

Comment: :D that worked. My question sounds so stupid now. I tried all sorts of things except this.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in a comment, Till Tantau advices: "Never ever use the evil option shrink."

That being said, you can the `\centering` command or the `center` environment to get the desired horizontal centering:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=50]
\centering
\textbf{Title of the slide}
\vskip10pt
Hi\par
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```